# What is the difference between on those two formate in c function?

Tags: c

What is the difference between on those two formate in C function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void basic_math(double* m_a, double* m_b, double* m_c) 
{ 
   *m_c = *m_a + *m_b;
}
int main () {
  double a = 2.5;
  double b = 3.2;
  double c;
  basic_math(&a, &b, &c); 

printf("ans is %.2lf\n", c); 
return 0;
 
}
```

if

```
void basic_math(double* m_a, double* m_b, double* m_c) 
{ 
   *m_c = *m_a + *m_b;
}
```

change into

```
void basic_math(double *m_a, double *m_b, double *m_c) 
{ 
   *m_c = *m_a + *m_b;
}
```

any difference on that?

Comment: @Lundin just edit the title

Comment: `void basic_math(double* m_a, double* m_b, double* m_c)` and `void basic_math(double *m_a, double *m_b, double *m_c)` are the same.

Comment: [Also relevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758270/why-is-the-asterisk-in-a-pointer-declaration-specific-to-the-identifier-and-not)

Comment: 13 answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180401/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-pointer-declarations). Also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400926/difference-between-and-pointers-in-c/30401234#30401234)